# Sound doesn't work with Intel 5 Series/3400 chipset

Tags: sound, drivers, hardware

Who can help me find the audio driver.
I got the following information after I ran sudo lshw and lspci

lshw

```
vun-k42jc 
description: Notebook
product: K42Jc
vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
version: 1.0
serial: A8N0AS67662035
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook uuid=8076F126-82B0-DF81-2D0D-20CF3045C9FA
*-core
description: Motherboard
product: K42Jc
vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
physical id: 0
version: 1.0
serial: BSN12345678901234567
slot: MIDDLE
*-firmware
description: BIOS
vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
physical id: 0
version: K42Jc.208 (07/21/2010)
size: 64KiB
capacity: 1984KiB
capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification
*-cpu
description: CPU
product: Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 460 @ 2.53GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 4
bus info: cpu@0
version: Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 460 @ 2.53GH
serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
slot: Socket 989
size: 1199MHz
capacity: 4GHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 133MHz
capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
*-cache:0
description: L1 cache
physical id: 5
slot: L1-Cache
size: 32KiB
capacity: 32KiB
capabilities: internal write-back unified
*-cache:1
description: L2 cache
physical id: 6
slot: L2-Cache
size: 256KiB
capacity: 256KiB
capabilities: internal varies unified
*-cache:2
description: L3 cache
physical id: 7
slot: L3-Cache
size: 3MiB
capacity: 3MiB
capabilities: internal varies unified
*-memory
description: System Memory
physical id: 41
slot: System board or motherboard
size: 2GiB
*-bank:0
description: DIMM [empty]
product: [Empty]
vendor: [Empty]
physical id: 0
serial: [Empty]
slot: DIMM0
*-bank:1
description: DIMM [empty]
product: [Empty]
vendor: [Empty]
physical id: 1
serial: [Empty]
slot: DIMM1
*-bank:2
description: SODIMM Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
product: AD73I1B1672EG
vendor: 04CB
physical id: 2
serial: 00000000
slot: DIMM2
size: 2GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
*-bank:3
description: DIMM [empty]
product: [Empty]
vendor: [Empty]
physical id: 3
serial: [Empty]
slot: DIMM3
*-pci:0
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 100
bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
version: 18
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
resources: irq:0
*-pci:0
description: PCI bridge
product: Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1
bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
version: 18
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:40 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:c0000000-d30fffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: GT218 [GeForce 310M]
vendor: nVidia Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a2
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 18
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:46 memory:d3400000-d37fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e080(size=8)
*-communication UNCLAIMED
description: Communication controller
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 16
bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d880a000-d880a00f
*-usb:0
description: USB Controller
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1a
bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
resources: irq:16 memory:d8808000-d88083ff
*-multimedia
description: Audio device
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1b
bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
resources: irq:47 memory:d8800000-d8803fff
*-pci:1
description: PCI bridge
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:41 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:d7400000-d87fffff ioport:7c000000(size=2097152)
*-pci:2
description: PCI bridge
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c.1
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:42 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:d6000000-d73fffff ioport:7c200000(size=2097152)
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 01
serial: 74:f0:6d:97:fa:27
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=2.6.35-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:17 memory:d6000000-d600ffff
*-pci:3
description: PCI bridge
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:43 ioport:a000(size=4096) memory:d4c00000-d5ffffff ioport:7c400000(size=2097152)
*-pci:4
description: PCI bridge
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1c.5
bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=pcieport
resources: irq:44 ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:d3800000-d4bfffff ioport:7c600000(size=2097152)
*-generic:0
description: System peripheral
product: SD/MMC Host Controller
vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
version: 80
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
resources: irq:18 memory:d3805000-d38050ff
*-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
description: SD Host controller
product: Standard SD Host Controller
vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
physical id: 0.2
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.2
version: 80
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d3804000-d38040ff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
physical id: 0.5
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.5
logical name: eth0
version: 03
serial: 20:cf:30:45:c9:fa
size: 100MB/s
capacity: 1GB/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.6 duplex=full ip=10.1.50.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100MB/s
resources: irq:48 memory:d3800000-d3803fff ioport:9100(size=128) ioport:9000(size=256)
*-usb:1
description: USB Controller
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1d
bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
resources: irq:23 memory:d8807000-d88073ff
*-pci:5
description: PCI bridge
product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1e
bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
version: a6
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
*-isa
description: ISA bridge
product: Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
*-storage
description: SATA controller
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
logical name: scsi0
logical name: scsi1
version: 06
width: 32 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
resources: irq:45 ioport:e070(size=8) ioport:e060(size=4) ioport:e050(size=8) ioport:e040(size=4) ioport:e020(size=32) memory:d8806000-d88067ff
*-disk
description: ATA Disk
product: ST9500325AS
vendor: Seagate
physical id: 0
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/sda
version: 0003
serial: 5VECRJ0R
size: 465GiB (500GB)
capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=e0c5913d
*-volume:0
description: Windows FAT volume
vendor: MSDOS5.0
physical id: 1
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
logical name: /dev/sda1
version: FAT32
serial: 3e5f-3a2b
size: 19GiB
capacity: 19GiB
capabilities: primary hidden fat initialized
configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
*-volume:1
description: Windows NTFS volume
physical id: 2
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
logical name: /dev/sda2
logical name: /media/OS
version: 3.1
serial: 0a2938d9-aa3b-9243-bdc3-a0842ee3d7a0
size: 116GiB
capacity: 116GiB
capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2011-01-07 08:30:45 filesystem=ntfs label=OS mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
*-volume:2
description: Extended partition
physical id: 3
bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
logical name: /dev/sda3
size: 329GiB
capacity: 329GiB
capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
*-logicalvolume:0
description: HPFS/NTFS partition
physical id: 5
logical name: /dev/sda5
logical name: /media/DATA
capacity: 311GiB
configuration: mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
*-logicalvolume:1
description: Linux filesystem partition
physical id: 6
logical name: /dev/sda6
logical name: /
capacity: 17GiB
configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered state=mounted
*-logicalvolume:2
description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
physical id: 7
logical name: /dev/sda7
capacity: 840MiB
capabilities: nofs
*-cdrom
description: DVD-RAM writer
product: DVD A DS8A4S
vendor: Slimtype
physical id: 1
bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
logical name: /dev/cdrom
logical name: /dev/cdrw
logical name: /dev/dvd
logical name: /dev/dvdrw
logical name: /dev/scd0
logical name: /dev/sr0
version: JA22
capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-generic
description: Signal processing controller
product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.6
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
resources: irq:18 memory:d8804000-d8804fff
*-pci:1
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 101
bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
*-pci:2
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 102
bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
*-pci:3
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 103
bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
*-pci:4
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor QPI Physical 0
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 104
bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
*-pci:5
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor Reserved
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 105
bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.2
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
*-pci:6
description: Host bridge
product: Core Processor Reserved
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 106
bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.3
version: 05
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
```

lspci

```
vun@vun-K42Jc:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
07:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 80)
07:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 80)
07:00.5 Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question.Title is not clear and the question is not readable.Use code tags to make you output readable.Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell from those logs, so excuse me if I'm missing something, but have you ensured that the sound chipset is enabled in BIOS?

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/139567/340336

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with an HP G62-B70SP. Installing a package called `linux-backports-modules-alsa-lucid-generic` solved for me.

System information:

```
skorzen@g62:~$ sudo lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)

skorzen@g62:~$ uname -r
2.6.32-34-generic

skorzen@g62:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ID 270
Codec: Intel G45 DEVIBX
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find that package.

Answer (score 1):

Your audio Driver seems to be installed. Maybe you are experiencing an issue with your sound engine. Please put screenshots of the "Hardware", "Input" and "Output" tabs inside of the Sound Preferences Window. An example is provided here.

This answer may be changed if the requested screenshot is placed inside of the original question.

Good luck!

[image]

[image]

[image]