# How can I test if input device (mic) is detected?

Tags: microphone, input-devices, msi

My friend's Ubuntu 12.04 is installed with Wubi and there is no Input device in Sound settings. Is there a command to see if there is something visible for the system or a fix for this?

It is a laptop - [MSI x360](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/X360.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/61289/how-to-verify-if-my-microphone-input-is-dead-or-ubuntu-not-detected-it-yet-i-ca

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the steps at-
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting for troubleshooting your soundcard.

If you just want to test, this post might help you-
[How to verify if my microphone input is dead or ubuntu not detected it yet? I can hear music but i cant record audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61289/how-to-verify-if-my-microphone-input-is-dead-or-ubuntu-not-detected-it-yet-i-ca)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer link:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
```

it may help you , i installed all things by these instruction...
In some cases, the procedures listed in this may not "simple fixes" and can cause problems later if the card needs to be replaced. It may be easier to simply replace or add a new card from the start rather than risk damaging the installation. 
So Be careful....