# Issue with audio after installing an additional gpu with an hdmi connection

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, hdmi, soundcard

TLDR: I added a GTX 1080 in addition to my current graphics card, and now default audio is not working.

### **Before:**

I had a working sound on Ubuntu 16.04, 4.15.0-38-generic. I had a GTX 740 graphics card and an NVidia driver (for CUDA). And a sound was working (from whatever is on the motherboard). Headphones worked, back audio jack worked. I installed a second graphics card GTX 1080 (which has an hdmi output), (no upgrade to software).

### **After:**

Now I currently have 1 graphics card for gui/rendering and another graphics card (1080) for tensorflow (aka not used for visuals).

```
*****~$ pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.
```

However,

```
*****:~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
```

[Additionaly sound settings says "Dummy Output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZKEc.png)

### **Attempts:**

1. [Only HDMI audio since installing Nvidia card: onboard audio device has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176659/only-hdmi-audio-since-installing-nvidia-card-onboard-audio-device-has-disappear)

   Bios does not have an option for auto detecting sound card.