# Onboard audio not working after graphics drivers set

Tags: nvidia, sound, intel

I have just built a computer and installed 14.04 (trusty) from USB. When I was trying Ubuntu running off the USB the audio was working, as it was after I installed Ubuntu.

Then I changed my graphics to my graphics card -Gigabyte nvidia 960 4GB DDR5, dual DVI-I/D + Display port + HDMI, and the audio stopped working. The graphics are working fine.

I believe the problem is that the audio is now being routed through my graphics card to the HDMI, but I am unable to test this as I have no HDMI devices.

I have checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176659/only-hdmi-audio-since-installing-nvidia-card-onboard-audio-device-has-disappear) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138907/hdmi-onboard-sound-works-but-no-analog-sound?rq=1), but have ensured that my Intel Audio is set to enabled in the BIOS. I have also tried following the fix suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138907/hdmi-onboard-sound-works-but-no-analog-sound/139567#139567) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/703464/comments/3), but changing this conf file has not given me any fix.

I think that Ubuntu is still recognising the motherboard audio, but is not allowing it to be selected any more.

From lshw:

```
...
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: NVIDIA Corporation
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
            version: a1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:17 memory:df080000-df083fff

...
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 31
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:df220000-df223fff memory:df200000-df20ffff
```

...

And from `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Anyone got any pointers? Feel free to ask any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer: the same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672187/no-audio-output-devices-detected-in-new-computer-build-with-skylake-z170-mothe) question: Install the `oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid-dkms` package from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages).